# How can I tell if the user is a new visitor or returning? analytics.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm using Google's [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) and I need to know if the user is a new or returning visitor via javascript when they're on the website. Is there a way to get this information?

Comment: Yes you can login into Google Analytics, under audience overview section you will see tab for new users.

Comment: I need to know programmatically when the user visits the website, so I can use the data.

Comment: If that data exists in the GA cookie I could just extract it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in order to track the users using a cookie id:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id

Basically, this code will create a unique user id for the current user, and then you can check if it has been stored in localStorage, in order to check if the user have visited your site in the past:

```
var GA_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'ga:clientId';

if (window.localStorage) {
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', {
        'storage': 'none',
        'clientId': localStorage.getItem(GA_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)
    });
    ga(function(tracker) {
        localStorage.setItem(GA_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, tracker.get('clientId'));
    });
} else {
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
}
```

To check if the user id is stored in localStorage, use this:

```
var GA_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'ga:clientId', userId = false;

if (window.localStorage) {
    userId = localStorage.getItem(GA_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY);
}

if (userId) {
    // Old user
} else {
    // New user
}
```